# how can I find out if a condition for sell or buy met in either of the last n bars

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

How can I find out if a condition for sell or buy met in either of the last n bars in trading view pinescript

Comment: Questions that just repeat the title as the entire post body do not do well here. It shows a lack of effort. You should edit your post body to be more specific, and to include what efforts you've made to find an answer before posting here. See [ask] for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ta.barssince()` for that.

> ta.barssince(condition) → series int
>
> RETURNS Number of bars since condition was true.

```
//@version=5
indicator("ta.barssince")
// get number of bars since last buy
plot(ta.barssince(buy))
```

Comment: thank you and I am grateful for your answer. but to clarify further I am saying that the condition I want to put here is that : if the condition"buy'is within last 3 candles, then plot x. so I don't want the number of candles. I am providing it. I just want to know how to write the following;                                                       x= if "buy" is plotted in any of the last 3 candles and close≤open  . thanks in advance

Comment: Use it as a condition. `(ta.barssince(buy) < 3)` should tell you whether it is within the last 3 candles.